# MQ Explorer not opening with strmqcfg as mqm

Tags: linux, ibm-mq

I am trying to open MQExplorer as mqm with the strmqcfg command. I want to start the MQExplorer as mqm and I have the Xauthority set up, but it seems that strmqcfg cannot draq the splash screen for MQExplorer. I am quite new to MQ and to what java classes mq uses for drawing the UI, so i don't know how tto fix this error. I have seen that you must delete and re-create the workspace, but i do not want to loose all my queue manager data. I am getting this error when I run the strmqcfg command as the mqm user:

```
No protocol specified
MQExplorer: Cannot open display: 
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
MQExplorer: Cannot open display: 
MQExplorer:
An error has occurred. See the log file
/var/mqm/IBM/WebSphereMQ/workspace/.metadata/.log.
```

The log contains this message:

```
!SESSION 2016-11-22 12:46:59.383 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.fullversion=JRE 1.7.0 IBM J9 2.7 Linux amd64-64 Compressed References 20150630_255653 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R27_Java727_SR3_20150630_2236_B255653
JIT  - tr.r13.java_20150623_94888.01
GC   - R27_Java727_SR3_20150630_2236_B255653_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20150630_255653
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -clean

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse 4 0 2016-11-22 12:47:01.079
!MESSAGE Unable to load parent configuration from: /opt/mqm/bin/@MQ.INSTALLATION.PATH/mqexplorer/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.update/platform.xml

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-11-22 12:47:04.046
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed]
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4423)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:925)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:909)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:507)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:691)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:162)
    at com.ibm.mq.explorer.ui.rcp.internal.base.RcpApplication.start(RcpApplication.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

I tried to start it with the -x flag for debugging and it gave me this information:

```
Start VM: /opt/mqm/java/jre64/jre/bin/java
-Xmx512M
-jar /opt/mqm/bin//../mqexplorer/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /opt/mqm/bin/MQExplorer
-name MQExplorer
--launcher.library /opt/mqm/bin//../mqexplorer/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130807-1835/eclipse_1506.so
-startup /opt/mqm/bin//../mqexplorer/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 1630016
-consolelog
-debug
-vm /opt/mqm/java/jre64/jre/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xmx512M
-jar /opt/mqm/bin//../mqexplorer/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar 
Install location:
    file:/opt/mqm/mqexplorer/eclipse/
Configuration file:
    file:/opt/mqm/mqexplorer/eclipse/configuration/config.ini loaded
Configuration location:
    file:/var/mqm/.eclipse/com.ibm.mq.explorer.ui.rcp.RcpApplication_8.0.0.201510221435_1223531284_linux_gtk_x86_64/configuration/
Configuration file:
    file:/var/mqm/.eclipse/com.ibm.mq.explorer.ui.rcp.RcpApplication_8.0.0.201510221435_1223531284_linux_gtk_x86_64/configuration/config.ini loaded
Loading timestamp file from:
     file:/var/mqm/.eclipse/com.ibm.mq.explorer.ui.rcp.RcpApplication_8.0.0.201510221435_1223531284_linux_gtk_x86_64/configuration/   .baseConfigIniTimestamp
Timestamps found: 
     config.ini in the base: 1476256974000
     remembered 1476256974000
Shared configuration location:
    file:/opt/mqm/mqexplorer/eclipse/configuration/
Framework located:
    file:/opt/mqm/mqexplorer/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.1.v20130814-1242.jar
Loading extension: reference:file:org.eclipse.osgi.nl1_3.9.1.v201309250800.jar
    eclipse.properties not found
Loading extension: reference:file:org.eclipse.osgi.nl2_3.9.1.v201309250800.jar
    eclipse.properties not found
Loading extension: reference:file:org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook_1.0.200.v20130327-1442.jar
    eclipse.properties not found
Framework classpath:
    file:/opt/mqm/mqexplorer/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.1.v20130814-1242.jar
    file:/opt/mqm/mqexplorer/eclipse/plugins/
    file:/opt/mqm/mqexplorer/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi.nl1_3.9.1.v201309250800.jar
    file:/opt/mqm/mqexplorer/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi.nl2_3.9.1.v201309250800.jar
    file:/opt/mqm/mqexplorer/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook_1.0.200.v20130327-1442.jar
Splash location:
    /var/mqm/.eclipse/com.ibm.mq.explorer.ui.rcp.RcpApplication_8.0.0.201510221435_1223531284_linux_gtk_x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher/com.ibm.mq.explorer.branding_8.0.0.201510221435/splash.bmp
No protocol specified
MQExplorer: Cannot open display: 
Debug options:
    file:/opt/mqm/bin/.options not found
Time to load bundles: 9
Starting application: 1579
No protocol specified
!SESSION 2016-11-22 12:52:53.856 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.fullversion=JRE 1.7.0 IBM J9 2.7 Linux amd64-64 Compressed References 20150630_255653 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R27_Java727_SR3_20150630_2236_B255653
JIT  - tr.r13.java_20150623_94888.01
GC   - R27_Java727_SR3_20150630_2236_B255653_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20150630_255653
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -consolelog -debug

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-11-22 12:52:55.621
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed]
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4423)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:925)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:909)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:507)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:691)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:162)
    at com.ibm.mq.explorer.ui.rcp.internal.base.RcpApplication.start(RcpApplication.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
No protocol specified
MQExplorer: Cannot open display: 
MQExplorer:
An error has occurred. See the log file
/var/mqm/IBM/WebSphereMQ/workspace/.metadata/.log.
```

Comment: This looks more like an X11 error where you're either specifying an invalid screen or don't have authority for the one you're trying to use.

Comment: Thank you VERY much! I just ran "xhost +" from a command line and now any user can access the display to open MQExplorer.